# Construction of this sentence in German?

Tags: sentence-structure, standard-german

> Die Situation ist noch schwieriger in anderen Staaten.

or

> Die Situation ist in anderen Staaten noch schwieriger.

Comment: The 2nd version is better. The first version sounds a lot like slang, as if the speaker forgot that detail and added it to the end of the sentence.

Comment: The first sentence is dangerous because people may hear *Die Situation ist noch schwieriger **als** in anderen Staaten.* which means the exact opposite. The *als* is usually contracted to a very short *ats* which makes listeners automatically expand it at that place even when it wasn't there.

Comment: The first form would be perfectly acceptable for a sentence that continues to list states:  "Die Situation ist noch schwieriger in anderen Staaten: Australien und Neuseeland sind noch mehr auf funktionierende Flugverbindungen angewiesen"

Answer (score 5):

Both are possible. In fact, you could also move "noch schwieriger" or "in anderen Staaten" to the first position. Word order in German is rather flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Version 2 is better, but even better (more idiomatic) would be

> (3) In anderen Staaten ist die Situation noch schwieriger.

Why is this? Because the German *Verbklammer* applies to predicative complements as well as to verbal complements.
Presumably you know that

> *Ich habe ihn getroffen gestern.

is dispreferred and

> Ich habe ihn gestern getroffen.

is preferred. The reason is that the elements of the *Verbklammer* are supposed to go *around* elements that modify the verbal phrase (*Verbletztstellung*). This is the reason that German verbs often come so late in the sentence (and the butt of a venerable tradition of jokes about the German language, starting at least with Mark Twain).

The same principle applies to predicative complements ("sein" + adjective). Here, too, material associated with the predicative expression is supposed to go *between* the elements of that expression. Since this delays the important part of the sentence until the end, a popular alternative is to *topicalize* the adverbial as in version (3). That way, the meaning-carrying word "Situation" and "schwieriger" are closer together and slightly easier to understand.

Comment: "ich habe ihn getroffen gestern" is a fault. In a clause like this the past participle has to be the last word.

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible. The difference is that in the first sentence I'd expect a (relative) clause to follow, which describes the other states. For example:

> Die Situation ist noch schwieriger in anderen Staaten, deren Bürger ebenfalls ...
>   Die Situation ist noch schwieriger in anderen Staaten mit hohem Anteil von...

The second sentence puts some emphasis on "die Situation". Another possible word order would be:

> In anderen Staaten ist die Situation noch schwieriger.

That word order would put some emphasis on "die anderen Staaten".